# Hibernate - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The problem is when calling an HQL, ones times get the correct responce or return this log error:

```
DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was  902,724 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 23,553 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45).

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3964)
... 96 more
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
ERROR SqlExceptionHelper - Communications link failure
```

Comment: Please check (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

Comment: there is the problem with the connection, thanks for the response!!!